# Why html() function in JQuery does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below runs well in chrome and ff, but the content in #cf_intro would not change with the timer in IE. ('Flow' is a plugin object.)

```
    timer=setInterval("m2n()",10000);   
    function m2n()
    {
        Flow.moveTo("next");
        var activeItemIntro=$('.active canvas').attr("intro");
        $("#cf_intro").html(activeItemIntro);
    }
    $(function(){
        function cf_timer(){
                timer=setInterval("m2n()",10000);
            }
        $('.flow').mouseover(function(){
                clearInterval(timer);
            })
        $('.flow').mouseout(function(){
                cf_timer();
            })
    })
```

Comment: Are you using a version of IE that supports canvas? (e.g. IE9?)

Comment: `attr("intro")`? It might help if you worked with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using canvas..

Canvas are only in HTML5 which means higher versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE9 (major browsers)

If you have IE8, it won't work